# the program written in fortran 95 and it showing warning integer division truncated to '0' [-Winteger-division] and some output data is NaN

Tags: fortran

the program is about solving continuity [w(1)], momentum [w(2)] and energy [w(3)] equations using FVM method and Lax Wendroff scheme for shock tube. please provide suggestions in equations also. and give suggestion how to eliminate the warnings. the line truncated is also one more error i aced in long equations.

```
    enter code here
program oneD_heatEqn

implicit none !  Variables must be declared
this program aout shock tube solving the continuity, momentum and energy equations using FVM and Lax Wendroff Scheme.
integer,parameter:: n = 100   ! number of points in the grid
real:: tmax = 0.1! time of the simulation
real:: dt !time step
real:: c !
real::h

real:: time = 0
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w1
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w2
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w3
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w4
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w5
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: u
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w1new
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w2new
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w3new
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w4new
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: w5new
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: A
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: A1
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: A2
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: E
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: Enew
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: p
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: pnew
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: T
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: unew
real(kind=4),dimension(n):: Tnew

integer::i

h = 1/real(n) ! Be careful to operate with variables of the same type.

dt=h/(340)
c=(340*dt)/h
!Set Boundary Conditions
w1 (1) =1.346
w2 (1)=0
w3 (1)=387849.9
e  (1)=1000*288.15
p  (1)=1113250
w1 (n)=1.225
w2 (n)=0
w3 (n)=(101325*1000*288.15)/(287*288.15)
e  (n) =1000*288.15
p  (n)=101325



!Set Initial Conditions
w1(2:50) = 1.346
w2 (2:50)=0
w3 (2:50)=387849.9
e(2:50)=1000*288.15
p(2:50)=111325
w1(51:N-1)=1.225
w2 (51:N-1)=0
w3 (51:n-1)=(101325*1000*288.15)/(287*288.15)
e  (51:n-1) =1000*288.15
p  (51:n-1)=101325
T(1:n)=288.15
u(1:n)=0
do i=1,n
w4(i)= w2(i)*((w3(i)/w1(i))+(p(i)/w1(i)))
w5(i)=(((w2(i))**2/w1(i))+p(i))
end do

write(*,*) "c=",c, 'dt=',dt
write(*,*) "w4=",w4
write(*,*) "w5=",w5


OPEN(unit=1,file="datau=0final .dat")

c1: do while ( time < tmax) !Note that you can numerate/name the loop (easier to know where you are)
   w1new(1)= w1(1)
   w4new(1)=w4(1)
    w3new(1)=w3(1)
   w5new(1)=w5(1)
   w2new(1)=w2(1)
   unew(1)=u(1)
   enew(1)=e(1)
   pnew(1)=p(1)
   Tnew(1)=T(1)
   L2: do i = 2, n-1
      !continuity equation
          A(i-(1/2))=(w2(i-1)+w2(i))/2
          A(i+(1/2))=(w2(i)+w2(i+1))/2
          w1new(i)=w1(i)-((dt/2*h)*(w2(i+1)-w2(i-1)))+(dt**3)/(2*h**2)*((A(i+(1/2))*(w2(i+1)-w2(i)))-(A(i-(1/2))*(w2(i)-w2(i-1))))
          !energy equation
         w4new(i)= w2(i)*((w3(i)/w1(i))+(p(i)/w1(i)))
         A1(i-(1/2))=(w4(i-1)+w4(i))/2
         A1(i+(1/2))=(w4(i)+w4(i+1))/2
         w3new(i)=w3(i)-((dt/2*h)*(w4(i+1)-w4(i-1)))+(dt**3)/(2*h**2)*((A1(i+(1/2))*(w4(i+1)-w4(i)))-(A1(i-(1/2))*(w4(i)-w4(i-1))))
         !momentum equation
         w5new(i)=(((w2(i))**2/w1(i))+p(i))
         A2(i-(1/2))=(w5(i-1)+w5(i))/2
         A2(i+(1/2))=(w5(i)+w5(i+1))/2
         w2new(i)=w2(i)-((dt/2*h)*(w5(i+1)-w5(i-1)))+(dt**3)/(2*h**2)*((A2(i+(1/2))*(w5(i+1)-w5(i)))-(A2(i-(1/2))*(w5(i)-w5(i-1))))
         unew(i)=w2(i)/w1(i)
         !other equations
         Enew(i)=(w3(i)/w1(i))-((1/2)*(w2(i)/w1(i))**2)
         pnew(i)=0.4*w1(i)*e(i)
         Tnew(i)=p(i)/(w1(i)*287)
      end do L2
         w1new(n)= w1(n)
         w4new(n)=w4(n)
         w3new(n)=w3(n)
         w5new(n)=w5(n)
         w2new(n)=w2(n)
          Unew(n)=u(n)
         Enew(n)=E(n)
         pnew(n)=p(n)
         Tnew(n)=T(n)
   w1(1:N)=w1new(1:N) ! Overwrite old value by new values
    w4(1:N)=W4new(1:N)
   w3(1:N)=w3new(1:N)
   w5(1:N)=W5new(1:N)
   w2(1:N)=w2new(1:N)
   u(1:N)=unew(1:N)
   e(1:N)=enew(1:N)
   p(1:N)=pnew(1:N)
   T(1:N)=Tnew(1:N)
   time = time + dt

   if (mod(int(time/Dt),int(tmax/Dt)/100)==0) then
     write(*,fmt="(F10.3,1X,I5,'% completed',A)",advance='yes') time, int(100*time/tmax), char(13) ! Overwrite the line
   end if
   if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', w1(1:N) ! Do output but keep only 100 profils
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', w2(1:N)
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', w3(1:N)
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', e(1:N)
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', p(1:N)
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', u(1:N)
if (mod(int(time/dt),int(tmax/dt)/100)==0) write(1,*) 'node(i)=1,N', T(1:N)
end do c1

write(*,fmt="(1X,I5,'% completed',A)") int(100*time/tmax), char(13)
call system('gnuplot -p output.plt')
 close(1)

write(*,*) "Program finished successfully"

end program oneD_heatEqn
```

Comment: `1/2` is zero in Fortran and in many other programming languages.

Comment: sir, thanks for reply can you suggest the method for removing line truncation error and how to solve conservation equation for shock tube using FVM method

Comment: It is simply typing in 1.0/2.0 instead of 1/2. As Vladimir points out, many languages see 1/2 and assume you deliberately are trying to do integer arithmetic and compile it as such. I recommend a decimal point with all your literal numbers in your program.

Comment: @SasindraReddyDappili Please see the link at the top and also be sure to take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. It is very important. If you have any further error after you fix the truncation, ask a new question. Be aware that here we can only help you with specific programming problems, not with physics simulations in general.